# swift 4 to remove only one annotation (not all)

Tags: swift, annotations, mapkit

the way to remove all annotations is below, but what i need is to remove a specific annotation

```
self.mapView.annotations.forEach {
    if !($0 is MKUserLocation) {
        self.mapView.removeAnnotation($0)
    }
}
```

or

```
func removeAllAnnotations() {
    let annotations = mapView.annotations.filter {
        $0 !== self.mapView.userLocation
    }
    mapView.removeAnnotations(annotations)
}
```

i tried to search two days ago but no help, could someone advise me. sorry for bothering you

the annotation array as below

```
array = [{annotationID: 1234, anotationTitle: "myLocation"},
         {annotationID: 321, anotationTitle: "locationMy"}]
```

i wanna remove

```
{annotationID: 1234, anotationTitle: "myLocation"}
```

how can?

Comment: Does your annotation have something to identify it?

Comment: yes, it has NSDictionary format. All annotations are in an array

Comment: Please show more context for this code, to help you.

Comment: Sasuke, i edit the question with array detail, could you please help to have a look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some ways to do it. If you can identify the title, try the following code.

```
func removeSpecificAnnotation() {
    for annotation in self.mapView.annotations {
        if let title = annotation.title, title == "myLocation" {
            self.mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i may use the id